# Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain - kinesis-kafka-connector

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to use Kafka-Kinesis-Connector is a connector to be used with Kafka Connect to publish messages from Kafka to Amazon Kinesis Firehose, as mentioned in the link (https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-kafka-connector) and getting a below error. I am using Cloudera version CDH-6.1.0-1.cdh6.1.0.p0.770702 and it ships with Kafka 2.1.2 (0.10.0.1+kafka2.1.2+6).

I have loaded the AWS credentials in the current sessions, This didn't work.

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="XXX"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="YYYYY"
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="sssss"
```

My worker.properties as shown below

```
bootstrap.servers=kafkanode:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
#internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
#internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=true
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.file.filename=offset.log
schemas.enable=false
#Rest API
rest.port=8096
plugin.path=/home/opc/kinesis-kafka-connector-master/target/
#rest.host.name=
```

My kinesis-firehose-kafka-connector.properties as shown below

```
name=kafka_kinesis_sink_connector
connector.class=com.amazon.kinesis.kafka.FirehoseSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=OGGTest
region=eu-central-1
batch=true
batchSize=500
batchSizeInBytes=1024
deliveryStream=kafka-s3-stream
```

The Error code is as shown below:

```
        [2019-01-26 11:32:24,446] INFO Kafka version : 2.0.0-cdh6.1.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:109)
  [2019-01-26 11:32:24,446] INFO Kafka commitId : unknown (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:110)
  [2019-01-26 11:32:24,449] INFO Created connector kafka_kinesis_sink_connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:104)
  [2019-01-26 11:32:25,296] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=kafka_kinesis_sink_connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
  com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:131)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1164)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:762)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:724)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisfirehose.AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient.doInvoke(AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient.java:826)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisfirehose.AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisfirehose.AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient.describeDeliveryStream(AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient.java:451)
    at com.amazon.kinesis.kafka.FirehoseSinkTask.validateDeliveryStream(FirehoseSinkTask.java:95)
    at com.amazon.kinesis.kafka.FirehoseSinkTask.start(FirehoseSinkTask.java:77)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:301)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:190)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 [2019-01-26 11:32:25,299] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=kafka_kinesis_sink_connector-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:178)
 [2019-01-26 11:32:33,375] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:65)
 [2019-01-26 11:32:33,375] INFO Stopping REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:223)
```

Please advise. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you ran those exports immediately before `connect-standalone`? If so, that has worked fine for me

Comment: @cricket_007  Thanks for your reply. I did try the same but, it is not working. Just wondering, did you altered or customized the Kinesis Kafka connector files before building jar file (`mvn install`) as mentioned it the source GitHub site. Please advise.

Comment: I've only done this with the S3 Connector, not the Kinesis one. But `AWSCredentialsProviderChain` should work the same, regardless. Exports don't need set for `mvn package` (you don't need to actually install this connector, only package it)

Comment: @cricket_007, thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

The ~/.aws/credentials file located in the home directory of the operating system user that runs the Connect worker processes. These credentials are recognized by most AWS SDKs and the AWS CLI. Use the following AWS CLI command to create the credentials file:

> aws configure

You can also manually create the credentials file using a text editor. The file should contain lines in the following format:

> [default]
>   aws_access_key_id = 
>   aws_secret_access_key =

***NOTE*** : When creating the credentials file, make sure that the user creating the credentials file is the same user that runs the Connect worker processes and that the credentials file is in this user's home directory. Otherwise, the S3 connector will not be able to find the credentials.